# private constructor usage in class

Tags: java

If there is a private constructor, does the JVM insert a call to the super constructor?

I'm referring to the `super()` call in that private constructor.

```
class Alpha {
    static String s="";
    protected Alpha(){
        s+="alpha";
    }
}

class SubAlpha extends Alpha{
    private SubAlpha(){
        s+="sub";
    }
}

class SubSubAlpha extends Alpha{
    private SubSubAlpha(){
        s+="subsubAlpha";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new SubSubAlpha();
        System.out.print(s);   
    }
}
```

Here I don't get any compilation error. Here in the `SubSubAlpha` class there is private constructor. Is that compiler insert `super()` call in that if so, what happens in the `SubAlpha` class. Even there is private constructor. And if that is not accessed how the inheritance tree continues till the top.

Comment: (If the super class' no-args constructor is private (and derived class is not in the same outer class; or is default access and derived class is not in the same package; or is just missing) then if the derived class' constructors are missing an explicit `super()` or `this()`, then they will fail to compile. `class Base { private Base() { } } class Derived extends Base { }`)

Comment: did you mean `class SubSubAlpha extends SubAlpha` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The private constructor has an implicit `super()` call if there is not explicit `super` or `this` constructor call.  In this respect, it is no different from other constructors.  Naturally, for this to compile, the superclass has to have a no-args constructor that is visible from the class.

However, if a constructor is `private`, it cannot be *called* from a subclass ... or from any other code apart from the class itself.

Answer (score 8):

> ***If there is private constructor does the JVM inserts call to super constructor?***

**Yes**

The super constructor will *always* be called. (You can't instantiate an class, without also instantiating the super class at the same time.)

If you don't do it explicitly yourself, there will be an implicit call inserted for you, no matter if the constructor is private or public.

---

To be picky: It's actually not the JVM that inserts it, but the Java compiler:

```
public class Test {
    private Test() {
    }
}
```

is compiled into

```
private Test();
  Code:
   Stack=1, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're not getting a compile-time error is that your class hierarchy isn't what you think it is. I think you meant this:

```
class SubSubAlpha extends Alpha {
```

to be this:

```
class SubSubAlpha extends SubAlpha {
```

... at which point you will indeed get a compile-time error.

(In other words, yes, there *is* always a call to the super-constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice example from the [Java Programmer's SourceBook](http://www.codeguru.com/java/tij/tij0065.shtml). Since the constructors print when called, you will see immediately the sequence of the calls. It is from Thinking in Java.

```
//: Cartoon.java
// Constructor calls during inheritance

class Art {
  Art() {
    System.out.println("Art constructor");
  }
}

class Drawing extends Art {
  Drawing() {
    System.out.println("Drawing constructor");
  }
}

public class Cartoon extends Drawing {
  Cartoon() {
    System.out.println("Cartoon constructor");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Cartoon x = new Cartoon();
  }
} ///:~
```

The output for this program shows the automatic calls:

Art constructor
Drawing constructor
Cartoon constructor

Answer (score -1):

Ya, u can use super() to use the function and attribute from the superclass. its the same with normal java