# Confused with private constructor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Studied in java that if a class have private constructor it cannot be inherited as `super()`, cannot be called,than why this code compiles, in case of inner class:

```
public class TestMe2 { 
    class Singleton { 
        private Singleton() { 
        } 
    } 
    class BB extends Singleton {  
    } 

    public void callMe(){ 
        Singleton sing=new BB(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663059/why-do-inner-classes-make-private-methods-accessible

Answer (score 2):

Because 2 inner classes of a common outer class have access to their respective private members.

Quote from [the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#d5e8146):

> A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The private keyword limits your access to the constructor/fubction/variable it is refered to, in the same file. This means that in an inner class you actually have access to the private constructor/method/variable

To add to my answer, if your BB was in a different file you would have a problem and the java compiler would ask you to define another non-default constructor

edit:
Mistakenly mentioning "same file". private keyword limits access to within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor

thanks @JB Niget

Comment: what do you mean by the same file, one file can have more than one java class, and the above code fails if the class are not inner class

Comment: You are correct, my mistake.
The answer to your comment is given by @jb-niget answer

Quote from the JLS:

A private class member or constructor is accessible only within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Answer (score 0):

`BB` is default constructed.  The default constructor is [package-private](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html), and [a class's constructor will always call the superclass constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5360859/1830736).  Specifically:

> If you don't do it explicitly yourself, there will be an implicit call inserted for you, no matter if the constructor is private or public.

So `Singleton.Singleton` will still be called by the subclass's constructor.  And yes, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense compared to, say, C++, where `private` really does mean `private`.

You can call `BB.BB` because you're calling it from the same package.

Comment: The question is: why can BB call the Singleton constructor, since it's private?

Comment: @JBNizet How was the question not answered?

Comment: The answer explains why you can call new BB(). It doesn't explain why the implicit BB cnstructor can call the private Singleton constructor, which is what the question is about.